# Translating encapsulated variables with Gettext

Tags: python, html, flask, internationalization, gettext

Good morning,
I'm internationalizing my Flask app with Gettext. However, I'm also using SQLalchemy, so many of the strings I need to translate are between curly braces.

```
<option value='{{c.id}}'>{{gettext({{c.nombre}})}}</option>
```

The code above, for instance, gives the output of {{c.nombre}}, instead of the actual output it should give, which is the string "Empresa". Any ideas on how to solve this? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like your using templating.   The stuff between {{}} is resolved by the templating engine by referencing the python.   c.id gets substituted in in the first spot.  in the later use you don't need the nested {{}} around c.nombre.   what will happen if you remove the nested braces is the result of getText(c.nombre) will be the value placed in the template.